# Add space plus stretch

Tags: spacing, line-spacing

I am trying to make a universal space that would always be put, even if there is already some space.

That is, if it is put before text in `flushright`, it shall push it beyond the margin.

I have created `\myspace` command with `plus` involved, however, it still doesn't work in `multline`, `flushright` and similar environmnets.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}

\newcommand{\myspace}[1]{\hspace{#1 plus \linewidth}}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline}
    abcabcabcabcabcabcabc\\
    ijkijkijkijkijkijkijkijk\\
    \myspace{3em}
    xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz
\end{multline}

test \myspace{3em} test

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: your space has a natural length of 3em but can stretch an additional `\linewidth` when needed. So the output is as I'd expect.

Comment: the last line of mulltine is flush right, what effect do you expect adding white space on the left will have, no space will make any difference unless you make it large enough to force an overfull box warning

Comment: And that's my question. How can I avoid putting additional large space till I will be able to affect the flushed text? And at the same time be able to insert the same space in a normal text. In a nutshell, a universal spacing command.

Comment: sorry I really can not guess what you want here. at the left side of a flush right line, you can add any space you like it will have no visible effect until you get an error situation that the text no longer fits on the line. so your first use does nothing. The second use makes a space of 3cm plus two word spaces as the \parfillskip at the end of the line means that no stretching is needed so the `plus \linewidth` does nothing.

Comment: Do you want to put a 3em *box* in the output? A fixed-width empty box will look like a space. `\newcommand{\myspace}[1]{\fbox{\makebox[#1]{}}}` `\fbox`  is just to make it visible.

Comment: What would the purpose be?

Comment: @Cicada it puts space to the left, it doesn't push the line out of margins.
https://imgur.com/q1YAftY

Comment: i don't understand what you want to do.

Comment: I want to force place a certain space i.e if I write `\myspace{3em}` in text, it should prodece what it currently does AND in addition to that be able to place the same `3em` space in `multline` or `flushedright` so that the text after `\myspace{3em}` is pushed beyond the margin.

Comment: adding a bounty is unlikely to encourage anyone to answer, you need to edit the question to make it clearer what you are asking, it is very hard to imaging what you want the 3em space in the multline to do, any possible definition that I could guess would have no effect in the output in that position.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell from your comments below the question, you want this, it makes the expression overshoot by 3em, I used the `*` form to suppress the equation number as your output didn't show a number and it would get over-printed.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{showframe}


\begin{document}

\begin{multline*}
    abcabcabcabcabcabcabc\\
    ijkijkijkijkijkijkijkijk\\
    xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz\hspace{-3em}
\end{multline*}

test\hspace{3em}test

\end{document}
```

Comment: Hmm... That might be a way to solve it. Then need to come up with a `xparse` code _(I guess)_ to make it work seamlessly -- like a command before before the shifted text.

Comment: @antshar you have not said what problem you are trying to solve or why you would ever want such a layout

Comment: I found out that if you put a text between `\hspace{3em}...\hspace{-3em}` it will work as I want. The only thing that I need now is to make a modal command for that, something like `\bfseries` macros, but in my case it should not make a bold text, but put it inside `\hspace{3em}...\hspace{-3em}`, so that the macros that is written like so:                               
`some text before the space \myspace{3em} xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz end line is here->` 
would actualy do:                                 
`some text before the space \hspace{3em}xyzxyzxyzxyzxyzxyz end line is here->\hspace{-3em}`