# xparse modal command – custom macro like \bfseries

Tags: macros, xparse

I would like to create a macro command that would put everything inside brackets for example or any other character, till the end of a line or till the end of a group `{\inchar ...}`. Something like a custom `\bfseries` command. Using default commands or `xparse`. It is interesting to see several implementation if possible.

That is, such an inputs should produce corresponding outputs

---

```
text text \inchar() text text text text

some other text on a new line
```

`↓`

```
text text (text text text text)
some other text on a new line
```

---

```
text text \inchar|] text text text text\\
some other text on a new line
```

`↓`

```
text text |text text text text]
some other text on a new line
```

---

```
text text \inchar\{\} text text text text\par
some other text on a new line
```

`↓`

```
text text {text text text text}
some other text on a new line
```

---

Also it should work in `amsmath` environments

```
\begin{multline*}
abc\\
\inchar() def\\
ghi \inchar\{\} jkl + mno
\end{multline*}
```

`↓`

```
abc
                                          (def)
                                                                           ghi {jkl + mno}
```

Comment: One point is not wholly clear.  By "end of the line", do you mean the end of the line *in the input file*, or do you mean the end of the line *in the typeset output*?

Comment: ...or do you mean the end of the paragraph?

Comment: I have edited. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: It is not clear. End of input line or end of output line?

Comment: @wipet of couse the `.pdf` is meant.

Comment: When macro is expanded then TeX cannot know where the line in the PDF output will be end. The paragraph breaking algorithm will be started later.

Comment: Sorry, but I cannot make a sense out of the request.

Comment: @egreg, I just don't want to make it complicated so the post contain a simple version of what I actually need, but with the solution I will be able to modify that for myself.

Comment: @antshar You've been asked to explain what you mean by “end of the line”, but you ignored what's really the main point towards a possible solution. Anyway, I see no motivation for the problem. If you want to fence some text, do it explicitly.

Comment: @egreg, by "end of line" I meant an end of a line after `\inchar`. A great example would be `\bfseries` it makes everything bold till the end of a line in your tex editor(line wrapping is not counting).
I can be more speciefic and tell the actual porpuse of this question. I am looking for the solution to this problem: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/546196 even with a bounty I have no luck getting an answer. I kinda thought up with a workaround that requires something that I am asking in this post.

Comment: @antshar `\bfseries` certainly does not do what you think. It goes on until the end of the current group.

Comment: @egreg yeah, I know. But if you don't put backets around `\bfseries` and some text it will affect everything till the end of a line.

Comment: @egreg, seems like I almost found the solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10426
The only problem is that it doesn't work if the line ends with `\\ `  or `\par`. Could you help me in tweaking that?

Comment: @antshar What is the expected precedence of `\\ `, `\par` and newline character? For example, in `text text<newline> text \\ text` and `text \\ text<newline>`, which newline-like input is taken as the marker?

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ the closest one. Either new line made by double pressing of Enter, or `\\ `, or`\par`.

Comment: @antshar From your examples in question, I understood that you want to use _single_ pressing of Enter as the marker of new line. Single Enter means `<line 1><Enter><line 2>`, while double Enter means `<line 1><Enter><empty line 2><Enter><line 3>`. Which one do you want?

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ single pressing of Enter in your LaTeX editor won't make a new line in the output file. So I meant a double pressing of the Enter which results an appearing of a new line.

Comment: @antshar 1) So you are talking about the new line or end of paragraph in output, inserted either automatically by TeX or manually by user. 2) But the linked question (https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/10426) actually only deals with the new line character in the input source. That misleads me a lot.

Comment: @antshar 3) At last, in your previous comment, you said "But if you don't put brackets around \bfseries and some text it will affect everything till the end of a line." That is not true. `\bfseries` will affect everything till the end of the current group, for example the end of document. Try `text \bfseries text <newline><newline> text text`.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ oh... sorry, my bad about `\bfseries` distribution to next lines. I don't know how to make it more clear, but I think you got me, "1)" says exactly what I would like to achieve.

Comment: @antshar Then, your needs cannot be fulfilled by normal TeX utilities (and techniques). I am not familiar with LuaTeX, maybe it is doable with Lua callbacks. Maybe you can post a new question, asking if LuaTeX can do that and how.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ is it possible, though, to make take it work at least with `\\ ` `\par`?

Answer (score 1):

A first try: `\autoScoped{<arg>}` opens a scope which can be auto ended by `\\` or `\par`, and then uses `<arg>`. Note this is *not the usual way that LaTeX should be used* and this first try is far from complete and might break many things.

Support for lists (including trivlist) is added. After trying, I find I am not capable of patching `amsmath` package yet. Sorry.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{xpatch}

\makeatletter
\newif\if@inscope

% start a local scope, nesting is not supported
\def\autoScoped{\@inscopetrue\ifmmode[\else\bfseries\fi}
% end a local scope
\def\end@scope@if@in{%
  \if@inscope
    \ifmmode]\else\mdseries\fi
    \@inscopefalse
  \fi}

% patch variants of \\
\@tfor\@tempa:=%
  \@normalcr % normal \\
  \@centercr % inside trivlist
\do{%
  \expandafter\xpretocmd\@tempa
    {\end@scope@if@in}
    {}{\fail}%
}
\let\\\@normalcr

% patch \par
\def\par@delimited{\end@scope@if@in\@@par}
\let\par\par@delimited
\def\@par{\let\par\par@delimited\par}
\def\@setpar#1{%
  \def\par{\end@scope@if@in#1}\def\@par{\end@scope@if@in#1}}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\newcommand\test[1][]{
  % case 1: delimited by \\
  #1\normalfont abc def \autoScoped ghi \\ jkl \par
  % case 2: delimited by explicit \par
  #1\normalfont abc def \autoScoped ghi \par jkl \par
  % case 3: delimited by implicit \par (consecutive newlines)
  #1\normalfont abc def \autoScoped ghi

  jkl \par
}

\setlength{\columnseprule}{.4pt}
\begin{multicols}{2}  
  \subsection*{Normal case}
  \test

  \subsection*{Inside trivlist and list}
  \begin{enumerate}
    \test[\item]
  \end{enumerate}

  \begin{center}
    \test
  \end{center}

  {\raggedleft \test \par}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: _I think the third example should be with a double Enter new line._ Wow, it works great. However, if I replace `\bfseries` and `\mdseries` with `[` and `]` respectively a space before `]` appers. Also it doesn't work in amsmath environments, unfortunately :(
https://imgur.com/4vF2dgB

Comment: @antshar 1) No, my answer cannot handle double Enter new line. 2) Generally, `\autoScoped` and `\end@scope@if@in` can only contain declarative commands, which means it should not produce any output. 3) Yes, and there are many many more cases (in `center` env, in `tabular` env, ...) it doesn't work. As I pointed in my answer, you almost should not use latex in this way.

Comment: 1) What do you mean? It works great for me with double Enter new line. 3) Why doesn't it work in those environments?

Comment: @antshar 1) TeX automatically converts consecutive new line characters to `\par`, so the patch to `\par` works. 2) Because in those environments, the definition of `\\` or `\par` (or both of them) is changed.

Comment: Is it possible to redefine `\\ ` glabaly. Or how can I redefine `\\ ` in them?

Comment: @antshar Support for list and `amsmath` envs is added.

Comment: Great! Almost perfect. Just to note, the original question is about adding characters from both sides. `\bfseries` was just for an example. But that is not the problem, because I can easily replace the condition with desired character. The problem that currently is – if you try to add this on the last line of the `multline` environment, bracket appears at the different spot: https://imgur.com/VV4dY3B         And also if I try to use several of commands on one line `a b \autoScoped c d \autoScoped e f` one bracket is missing: https://imgur.com/whiFagV

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109057/discussion-between-muzimuzhi-z-and-antshar).

Comment: Despite having no the perfect solution. You were the only who left an answer, so I will give you the points.